# Azure Logic Apps JSON Schema Validation - How to Invalidate Empty Strings?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I found when applying JSON Schema validation in Logic Apps [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziC7G.png) e.g.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziC7G.png)
[image]

```
 "FirstName": {
        "minLength": 1,
        "type": "string"
    }
```

Then Logic Apps does not invalidate when value is empty string.

Also, Logic Apps JSON Schema does not support using regular expressions like this

```
        "FirstName": {
        "minLength": 1,
        "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*$"
}
```

How to perform more sophisticated validation checks in Logic Apps including checking for valid email format and empty strings, without creating custom conditional activities?

Using JSON Schema validation in Parse JSON activity allows codeless summary of validation failures [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4iR5.png) e.g.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4iR5.png)
[image]
outputs('Parse_JSON')?['Errors']

Which would be lost if validation was to be handled outside of JSON Schema validation

Comment: There's a certified connector (`Advanced Data Operations`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/) that has this coming, so it's not available as of right now as a direct operation but it can be called via a HTTP operation ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/json-schema-validate/ ... all you need to do is supply an API key which you can get from here ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/pricing/

Comment: @Skin I am better off building and hosting my own Function App if I need to call a HTTP endpoint to do validation checks

Comment: Cool, if you’re capable then go ahead. Some people aren’t and some people don’t want the technical debt. Just trying to help man.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Logic Apps JSON Schema Validation - How to nvalidate Empty Strings?

To validate you can use below:

[image]

Then compose2:(For empty string validation)

```
empty(outputs('Compose'))
```

[image]

Output:

If string is empty you get output as true:

[image]

Added Response:

[image]

If is not empty:

[image]

> JSON Schema validation in Parse JSON activity allows codeless summary

Yes, validation is not possible if this is not handled by the `Parse Json Shema Validation` and used for codeless summaries.

[image]